# Whats the best java date recurrence pattern calculator

Tags: java, date, recurrence

Anyone know of a (reliable) date recurrence calculator, we're trying
to implement something in our app which would allow a schedule to be
created, similar to those for recurring meetings in Outlook. We have
tried chronos but discovered some cases where it breaks down, I'd
really appreciate knowing if anyone has successfully used any of the
other options out there.

Cheers,
Robin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a frequent question on the joda time mailing list and the usual answer is to try [RFC 2445](http://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/).  Disclaimer: I have not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Quartz, it's a really handy tool:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lamma date](http://lamma.io) (I wrote it recently), which is designed to generate dates based on a recurrence pattern.

For example:

```
import static io.lamma.LammaJavaImports.*;
Dates.from(2010, 1, 1).to(2019, 12, 31).byYears(3).on(Locators.nth(3, FRIDAY).of(FEBRUARY)).build();
```

will generate **the third Friday of February for every 3 years in 2010s**

Output:

```
List(2010-02-19, 2013-02-15, 2016-02-19, 2019-02-15)
```