# Converting recurrence rules for meetings into date

Tags: java, android

I'm creating my own custom calendar that reads off the user's calendar to find events. When I read the calendar I use Android's implementation of CalendarContract and read in all the events (recurring and non-recurring) The recurring events give a recurrence rule such as FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20140917T230000Z;WKST=MO;BYDAY=WE. I would like to use the recurrence rule to and decide when to schedule the meetings in my calendar as the user switches from month to month. Are there any examples or libraries out there that could help with this?

Comment: Another duplicate: [Whats the best java date recurrence pattern calculator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492055/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the google-rfc-2445 library at https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/downloads/detail?name=rfc2445-4Mar2011.jar&can=2&q= which solved my problem.